# datepicker on date hover popup

Tags: popup, datepicker, hover, onmouseover

I'm trying to get a week of dates with data for each day to popup when I hover over the week.  I can get it to popup up a display if I click on a date in a week, but I want it to happen on a mouseover/mouseenter.  Here is the code I have:

```
    <html>  
    <head>  
      <link href="./jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>  
      <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.min.js"></script>  
      <script src="./jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
      <script type="text/javascript" src="./popup.js"></script>

      <script>  

      var dateString;
      var sundayDate;
      var mondayDate;
      var tuesdayDate;
      var wednesdayDate;
      var thursdayDate;
      var fridayDate;
      var saturdayDate;


      $(document).ready(function() {  
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                showOtherMonths: true,
                selectOtherMonths: true,
                onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                    var date = new $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                    sundayDate    = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
                    mondayDate    = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 1);
                    tuesdayDate   = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 2);
                    wednesdayDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 3);
                    thursdayDate  = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 4);
                    fridayDate    = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 5);
                    saturdayDate  = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
                }
        });

        $('td a').live('mouseenter', function () {
            popup('<table border="1" width="350">' +
            '   <tr>' +
            '      <th>Su</th>' +
            '      <th>Mo</th>' +
            '      <th>Tu</th>' +
            '      <th>We</th>' +
            '      <th>Th</th>' +
            '      <th>Fr</th>' +
            '      <th>Sa</th>' +
            '   </tr>' +
            '   <tr height= "50px">' +
            '      <td valign="top" width = "50px">' + sundayDate.getDate() + '</td>' +
            '      <td valign="top" width = "50px">' + mondayDate.getDate() + '</td>' +
            '      <td valign="top" width = "50px">' + tuesdayDate.getDate() + '</td>' +
            '      <td valign="top" width = "50px">' + wednesdayDate.getDate() + '</td>' +
            '      <td valign="top" width = "50px">' + thursdayDate.getDate() + '</td>' +
            '      <td valign="top" width = "50px">' + fridayDate.getDate() + '</td>' +
            '      <td valign="top" width = "50px">' + saturdayDate.getDate() + '</td>' +
            '   </tr>' +
            '</table>');
        });

      });
    </script> 
    </head>  
    <body>  

    <div class="demo">
        <div id="datepicker"></div>
    </div>

    </body>  
    </html>
```

I had read something about using .on instead of .live, as that is the current method, but I still am lost as to how to get a date to get selected on a "mouseover" and it to pupup the current date.  I can handle formating the week's table look and inputing the data, but I want the date the mouse is over to be selected and trigger the onSelect action.

Thanks in advance for any repsonse to this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can trigger this by having a button or other object that contains something to the effect of:

```
<label onmouseover="mouseenter">move here</label>
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it well enough.  I'm wanting the week's table to popup when the user's mouse pointer is over a date on the datepicker calendar.